# How do I dynamically reflect the country code & flag on UI in vue-tel-input

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-tel-input

I'm receiving the country code from the back-end and want to show the same in the vue-tel-input form.

I'm using the below code, but its not working as expected.

```
    <vue-tel-input 
      :defaultCountry="defaultCountryCode" 
      :dropdownOptions="{showFlags:true,showDialCodeInSelection:true}" 
      @country-changed="setCountryCode"
    ></vue-tel-input>
```

for props refer: https://iamstevendao.github.io/vue-tel-input/documentation/props.html

Answer (score 1):

I realize I'm late here but this should fix it:

`:key="defaultCountryCode"`